# Im new to android how can i set random activities to my results button

Tags: android, android-studio, random

I'm having 4 activities other than `MainActivity`.
I have added results button and when the user click on that button a random activity should be opened.
Here's my `MainActivity` class and its XML:

```
    package tk.crazyapps.www.volleyupload;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Base64;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
    import com.android.volley.Request;
    import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
    import com.android.volley.Response;
    import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Hashtable;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Random;
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener  {

private Button buttonChoose;
private Button buttonUpload;

private ImageView imageView;

private EditText editTextName;

private Bitmap bitmap;

private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

private String UPLOAD_URL ="http://crazyapps.tk/VolleyUpload/upload.php";

private String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
private String KEY_NAME = "name";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttonChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoose);
    buttonUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);

    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    imageView  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(this);









}



public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}

private void uploadImage(){
    //Showing the progress dialog
    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Uploading...","Please wait...",false,false);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {
                    //Disimissing the progress dialog
                    loading.dismiss();
                    //Showing toast message of the response
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, s , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    //Dismissing the progress dialog
                    loading.dismiss();

                    //Showing toast
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, volleyError.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            //Converting Bitmap to String
            String image = getStringImage(bitmap);

            //Getting Image Name
            String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();

            //Creating parameters
            Map<String,String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();

            //Adding parameters
            params.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);
            params.put(KEY_NAME, name);

            //returning parameters
            return params;
        }
    };

    //Creating a Request Queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            //Setting the Bitmap to ImageView
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(v == buttonChoose){
        showFileChooser();
    }

    if(v == buttonUpload){
        uploadImage();
    }
}
```

**Here's the XML of** `MainActivity:`

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Choose Image"
    android:id="@+id/buttonChoose" />


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/imageView" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:hint="Enter ur Name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />


<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Upload Image"
    android:id="@+id/buttonUpload" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Results"
    android:id="@+id/buttonresult" />
```

Comment: Generate a random int between 1 and 4 and use it in if-elseif-elseif-else statements each opening individual activity :)

Answer (score 2):

```
int min = 0;
int max = 4;

Random r = new Random();
int random = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;

switch (random) {
    case 0:
        // start activity 0
        break;
    case 1:
        // start activity 1
        break;
    case 2:
        // start activity 2
        break;
    case 3:
        // start activity 3
        break;
}
```

Comment: better still, instead of having the overhead of creating activities, use one activity which uses a pager, where each page is a fragment and then you just set position randomly

Comment: The 'overhead of creating activities' depends on what these activities should do, maybe they're completely different. Your approach could be good but, why use a ViewPager with 4 fragments if i'm sure that only one fragment will be visible on that time?

Comment: Well simply because if there are 4 pages I think it is worth having the overhead of creating the fragments in one go once at the start, and then the user experience will be snappy when switching from one page to another as the view might not necessarily be destroyed and the fragments and state are kept in memory. This applies to FragmentPagerAdapter, there is another alternative with using FragmentStatePagerAdapter which only keeps the state if you want to save memory.